# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'personalDetails.firstName')

Tags: android, react-native

I am facing an issue where I can login to my React Native app on the `ios` side of things, but I cannot login on the android side of it.

The error I face in logcat says:

```
2019-08-28 14:33:01.638 31244-17613/com.nfibengage E/ReactNativeJS: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'personalDetails.firstName')

    This error is located at:
        in DetailsConfirmation (created by Connect(DetailsConfirmation))
        in Connect(DetailsConfirmation) (at SceneView.js:17)
        in SceneView (at CardStack.js:455)
        in RCTView (at View.js:35)
        in View (at CardStack.js:454)
        in RCTView (at View.js:35)
        in View (at CardStack.js:453)
        in RCTView (at View.js:35)
        in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
        in AnimatedComponent (at Card.js:12)
        in Card (at PointerEventsContainer.js:39)
        in Container (at CardStack.js:498)
        in RCTView (at View.js:35)
        in View (at CardStack.js:414)
        in RCTView (at View.js:35)
        in View (at CardStack.js:413)
        in CardStack (at CardStackTransitioner.js:67)
        in RCTView (at View.js:35)
        in View (at Transitioner.js:142)
        in Transitioner (at CardStackTransitioner.js:19)
        in CardStackTransitioner (at StackNavigator.js:41)
        in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:13)
        in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:226)
        in NavigationContainer (at RootNavigation.js:216)
        in RootNavigation (created by Connect(RootNavigation))
        in Connect(RootNavigation) (at App.js:249)
        in RCTView (at View.js:35)
        in View (at App.js:247)
        in Provider (at App.js:246)
        in NFIBEngage (at renderApplication.js:40)
        in RCTView (at View.js:35)
        in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
        in RCTView (at View.js:35)
        in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
        in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
2019-08-28 14:33:29.127 1738-1800/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-08-28 14:33:42.670 1822-1822/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-08-28 14:33:42.671 1822-1822/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
```

I noticed inside of `DetailsConfirmation.js`:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { personalDetails, personalAddress } = this.props.registeredUser;
    console.log(this.props.registeredUser);
    if (personalDetails) {
      this.props.firstNameChanged(personalDetails.firstName);
      this.props.lastNameChanged(personalDetails.lastName);
      this.props.suffixChanged(personalDetails.suffix);
      this.props.prefixChanged(personalDetails.prefix);
    }

    if (personalAddress && personalAddress.stateCode) {
      this.props.stateChanged(personalAddress.stateCode);
    }

    const { params = {} } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const { displayAlert = true } = params;

    this.state = {
      validationErrors: {},
      displayErrors: false,
      titleName: personalDetails.firstName,
      displayAlert
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.state.displayErrors) {
      this._validate(nextProps);
    }
  }
```

They have this all inside a constructor function which it really should go inside a `componentDidMount()`. I tried that approach but it did not resolve the error for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.state = {
  validationErrors: {},
  displayErrors: false,
  titleName: personalDetails.firstName, // <--- it causes an error
  displayAlert
};
```

You can avoid this error like this:

```
this.state = {
  validationErrors: {},
  displayErrors: false,
  titleName: personalDetails && personalDetails.firstName, // <--- it should be ok
  displayAlert
};
```

Comment: I had tried something similar but `||` instead of `&&`. The problem though, when it logs the user in, its logging an `undefined` user. So it says, `Welcome, undefined`. And again, this is only happening in `android` side.

Comment: it looks like there is no personalDetails in the props in android, what kind of authorization do you use?

Comment: what I did after I implemented your solution is I extracted out the logic from the constructor function, which was not a good place to have it and place it in a `componentDidMount()`, that seemed to work because I was able to login from then on with no problems.

Comment: I am back to getting this problem again. It seems that `titleName` is undefined.